# Powershell write to stdout (no newline)

Tags: powershell, outputstream

I need something absolutely simple but apparently totaly impossible. I need to write something to `stdout` in powershell.

So far I found only `write-output` but this unfortunately appends `linefeed`. I tried to somehow "hack" it by getting `stdout` from `.net` but I always get `host stream` which doesnt do what I want.

Do anyone knows a way how can I write for example `1` to `stdout` so when I pipe the script exactly `1` is on `stdin` of other script? I accept any kind of hack but I dont want to do redirection on invocation like `()sth>&1 | script`.

Comment: PowerShell is not like other shells. You are better off explaining the entire context of your problem; it may be that you are taking the wrong approach. PowerShell's pipe handles actual objects, rather than just text; if you are attempting to transfer information between two cmdlets, text is probably not the way to do it.

Comment: I want to create simple script that listens on tcp and writes all income bits as is to stdout. I would like then to pipe the data somewhere else. I would love to get the output stream handle and then just .Write()

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to write a C# application with PowerShell..

Comment: What is the 'somewhere else'? Is it a PowerShell script, a console program, or what? In PowerShell, the pipe does not always correspond to `stdout`, and strings are PowerShell objects. Don't think of PowerShell as bash with different syntax; there's a whole different mindset needed.

Comment: hmm.... I am trying to do what i could with `netcat` but without installing, compiling or anything like that... simple thing with standard tooling. apparently impossible :(

Comment: @JeffZeitlin "somewhere else" is another process's/cmdlet stdin.

Comment: process or cmdlet? That is a huge difference. Please simply provide your use case in a script or command, as far as you got it already.

Comment: There's actually no newline in a powershell string.  The carriage return and newline get added by set-content or out-file.

Answer (score 3):

I was going crazy trying to capture PowerShell output from a PowerShell command I executed from within a Python script. And it did not work because PowerShell does not properly write to STDOUT.

But I found some ways...

First is using the PowerShell command `Write-Information`:

```
Write-Information -Message "This goes to Stdout" -InformationAction Continue
```

The other is starting PowerShell with cmd and capture the output of cmd:

```
cmd.exe /C "powershell.exe -command "Write-Host 'This goes to Stdout'"
```